# Why did Planck took frequency from a wave and incorporated it to explain particle behavior of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Well if we assume anything to be a particle then it can never be a wave right??

But when planck developed his idea then he incorporated the frequency into the formula E = hv
but frequency is a character of waves, not particles ?

Comment: Yes, frequency is a wave property. But actually light is both, particle **and** wave. See [Wave-particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality).

Comment: Yes Thomas I agree your point that light is wave & particle both. But physicist don't take into account both at same time. For Example If we are talking about Photoelectric Effect, we take into account only the particle nature of light and their is no sign of wave property anywhere in the vicinity of P.effect.   And when we talk about Diffraction, its always the wave character we talk about. But here we are using one of a wave property to show quantization which is rather not a wave character. Why is so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Planck was trying to explain experimentally measured spectra of thermal EM radiation within electromagnetic theory, where radiation is a collection of waves. The formula

$$
\Delta E = hf
$$

was for quantum of energy by which energy of an oscillator can change, it does not in any way require that there be particles of light involved. The idea of particles of light never played any role in Planck's contributions.

It was Einstein and other physicists after him who pushed through the concept of particles of light, which carry energy $hf$.

Comment: But he told about quantization indeed.  In fact the exact formulation would be ∆E = nhf. That does not suggest a wave nature which would rather have a continuous than discrete nature. Is it not suggesting a particle character ?

Comment: To some people today yes, because the way how it is taught. But not to Planck - when you read Planck's works, it is clear he sticked to Maxwell's equations and continuous description of radiation. The formula was just additional assumption about the mechanics of energy exchange. Not derivable from, but also not contradicting wave description.

Answer (score 1):

Well certainly, he didn't told anything about particle behaviour. He was just trying to explain BBody radiation using quantisation.